# Installing packages using android command line tools

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, installation, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to use the android sdk without installing Android Studio because of hardware constraints. SYSTEM INFO[https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIsS4.png ]

So I've been following this tutorial https://dev.to/jay_js/setting-up-flutter-without-android-studio-olo so far so good, up until sdkmanager "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64"

When i try executing that code i get Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file. I went into my 'Android' directory and saw these files only:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY7KR.png ] (screenshot from my pc).

Further into tools directory:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD22G.png ]

Am i missing files or what?

NB i plan on using the sdk for visual studio code. Feel free to ask for more screenshots:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Linux Ubuntu:
Just execute the command below:

```
sudo chmod -R a+w [path/to/android/sdk]
```

Source:[https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-install-missing-android-tools/issues/57 ]